# Displaying objects based on CSS class on Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

I am trying to filter how products are displayed on a website. I have the product tags being added to the class of the item. One of the tags I have is "consumer".

I am wanting to only display products with the "consumer" tag and have come up with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if($("#product-item").hasClass('consumer')){
   $("#product-item").css({"display": "flex"});
  } else {
     $("#product-item").css({"display": "none"});
 }
</script>
```

Each product has an `id="product-item"` and I am looking to hide `"product-item"` if it doesn't have `class="consumer"`.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use another class instead.

Comment: @Andy how would the code look? I tried replacing the ID part of the code and it isn't working. I am using `.product-item` class

Comment: if class is added using liquid code then CSS is best for it, not need to use the javascript code.

Comment: @Onkar how would I do it using pure CSS?

Comment: if you send me the URL or code snapshot I will send you the CSS code, without checking HTML CSS code is harder to write

Comment: @Onkar will this work with multiple classes. I basically want to display commercial products to commercial customers and consumer products to consumer customers using a dropdown menu to pick between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So, first, IDs MUST be unique. So just add a new class to your classlist, and then loop over the product items.

```js
$('.product-item').each(function () {
  const el = $(this);
  if (el.hasClass('consumer')) {
    el.css({ 'display': 'flex' });
  } else {
    el.css({ "display": "none" });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <div class="product-item consumer">Tree</div>
  <div class="product-item">Bird</div>
  <div class="product-item consumer">Car</div>
  <div class="product-item">Shed</div>
  <div class="product-item consumer">Acorn</div>
</div>
```

Or, perhaps, the simpler:

```js
$('.product-item').not('.consumer').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <div class="product-item consumer">Tree</div>
  <div class="product-item">Bird</div>
  <div class="product-item consumer">Car</div>
  <div class="product-item">Shed</div>
  <div class="product-item consumer">Acorn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, managed to get it to all work for my specific configuration. You can check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/4vj3kgew/1/